# Http Connection in Android

Tags: android, http

i am new to android...
I want to connect with server .Like i want to sent data and recieve data from server through Http Connection..
Can anyone help me how to do this.
Can anyone provide me the sample of both side-client as well as server side.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I'm just starting reading about Android, but I'll throw in my two cents here. Apparently Android uses Apache HTTPComponents library to do what you are looking to do. You should check out the HttpClient tutorials here:
http://hc.apache.org/

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Sleepycat,thnks a lot for this file.Can you provide something same like this for android with samples.

Comment: Hey Remish, like I said I am just reading about this now. The book I am reading is "Beginning Android 2" from Apress. Its a great book.

Answer (score 1):

Quick working example using Apache HTTPComponents:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

try {
 String reqData = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler).toString();
 httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
 handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {           
 handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
} catch (IOException e) {
 handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
}
```

> private Handler handler = new
>   Handler() {
>            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
>
> ```
> switch (msg.what) {
>   case 0: {
>     // all ok, process data
>   } break;
>
>   case 1: {
>     // show some errors
>   } break;
>
> }   } };
> ```

Comment: Hi Alexandru Mos,thnks for the reply.Can you tell me what is handler here " handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);" because it is giving error.

Comment: Uhhh... sorry, I forget about the handler. Take a look here, http://commons.apache.org/io/description.html

Comment: Can you give me your email id so that i can contact you directly,if you dont have any prob

Comment: Hi i did like this bt google.com is not opening..
public class WebToolKit extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com"); 
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); 
         
        try { 
         String reqData = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler).toString(); 
         httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); 
         handler.sendEmptyMessage(0); 
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {            
         handler.sendEmptyMessage(1); 
        } catch (IOException e) {

Comment: handler.sendEmptyMessage(1); 
        } 

    }
    
    private Handler handler = new Handler() 
    { public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

     switch (msg.what) { 
       case 0: { 
         // all ok, process data 
       } break; 
      
       case 1: { 
         // show some errors 
       } break; 
      
     }   } }; 
}